# How can I split (yes/no) radio buttons from PHP echo?

Tags: php, joomla, k2

I'm using the Joomla CMS on my website and I have downloaded the `k2` plugin.

There is PHP code that I couldn't understand how to split so that I can style it the way I want.

```html
<?php echo ($this->row->published > 0) ? JText::_('K2_YES') : JText::_('K2_NO'); ?>
```

I want the "yes" alone and the "no" alone.

Comment: I don't think this is the code you're looking for. What you have provide will **only** show *Yes* if `$this->row->published` is greater than 0. Else it will show *No*

Comment: yes.. my bad i mixed up things -_- 
i meant this code

<td class="adminK2RightCol">
          <?php echo $this->lists['published']; ?>
         </td>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joomla JText class pull text from language file so JText::_('K2_YES') returns a text. Now you may separate or style your returned text as you want.

```
<?php
if($this->row->published > 0){
  echo JText::_('K2_YES');
 //style as u want '<h1>'.JText::_('K2_YES').'</h1>' etc.
}else{ 
  echo JText::_('K2_NO'); 
}
?>
```

Comment: Make sure to provide an explanation with your answer.